# What might be the cheapest ferry connection from near Athens to anywhere in Turkey?

Tags: budget, international-travel, ferries, turkey, athens

Soon I'm heading from Albania to Turkey to Georgia.

The obvious way is to go through Thessaloniki which is a great city and I'd like to go back.

But I'm considering an alternative plan of going via Athens instead. Now I don't like backtracking and I like being in new places and I like places with not many tourists and I like ferries. So I'm seeking a ferry option specifically.

Time is only a minor factor but budget is my biggest factor, both because I'm conserving my money but also because I enjoy the extra adventures travelling cheap always seems to provide.

So I really don't care where in Turkey I arrive. But Athens is a goal which probably means Piraeus as departure point. Departure date is early to mid October 2011 - soon!

**So from Athens/Piraeus/vicinity to anywhere in Turkey by sea, what ferry options are the best bargains?**

Comment: I think most of the ferry options end up down along the Mediterranean coast more than than they do Aegean or Marmara. Also they often do have other island stops along the way. Last time I looked into it it wasn't particularly cheap compared to Athens/Izmir airfare (but that was a promotional time). I'm sorry I can't find my notes on lines/routes I'd found or I'd answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may consider going to Chios and then to Cesme.
Here is more information: There are many different options from Piraeus to Chios. Prices start from 22.50€. From Chios to Cesme, I have found one line for 25€. [This site](http://www.greeka.com/eastern_aegean/chios/island/chios-ferries.htm) has the information related to pricing and time tables. You need to select your departure and arrival points from the menus.

Answer (score 8):

There is a ferry between [Piraeus and Samos](http://www.ferries.gr/hellenicseaways/ferries-piraeus-ikaria-samos.htm) at about 50€, then another ferry between [Samos and Kuşadası](http://www.meandertravel.com/ferrytosamos/samos.php?details=ferrytosamos&m=4&md=sc4) at about 35€.

Comment: The Piraeus-Samos ferry looks like a bargin for the distance compared to the Samos-Kusadasi ferry.